# How to convert group by with join from SQL Server to Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have this code in SQL Server:

```
select SUM(td.Valor) as Total, s.Nome as [Servico Prestado] from Transacao tr
left join TransacaoDivisao td on tr.CodTransacao = td.CodTransacao
left join ServicosPrestado sp on td.CodServicoPrestado = sp.CodServicosPrestado
left Join servico s on sp.CodServico = s.CodServico
GROUP by s.nome order by 1 desc
```

but when I tried convert to linq, i have this:

```
var res = 
  from transacao in dbContext.Transacao
  join td in dbContext.TransacaoDivisao on transacao.CodTransacao equals td.CodTransacao
  join sp in dbContext.ServicosPrestado on td.CodServicoPrestado equals sp.CodServicosPrestado
  join s in dbContext.Servico on sp.CodServico equals s.CodServico


  group s by s.Nome into gp
  select new
  {
      servicoPrestado = gp.Key,
      td.Valor // throw error
  };
```

Comment: there's an example here of `sum with group by` http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-sum/

Comment: `throw error` - Which error? Also, try to use navigation properties instead of joins. For example `Transacao.TransacaoDivisao`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is inner join in your code where as in sql you have written left join , so i m gonna go with left join

```
var res=(from tr in dbContext.Transacao
         join td in dbcontext.TransacaoDivisao
         on tr.CodTransacao equals td.CodTransacao
         into r11
         from r1 in r11.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join sp in dbcontext.ServicosPrestado
         on r1.CodServicoPrestado equals sp.CodServicosPrestado
         into r22
         from r2 in r22.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join s in dbContext.CodServico
         on r2.CodServico equals s.CodServico
         into r33 
         from r3 in r33.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new {r1,r3})
         .GroupBy(x=>x.r3?.Nome)
         .Select(x=>new 
                    {
                      Total=x.Sum(z=>(z.r1==null?0:z.r1.Valor)),
                      Servico Prestado=x.Key
                    })
         .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Key)
         .ToList();
```